# Cassandra: is Timestamp Entry in a Row callable with CQL?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

when you put an entry in the DB,Cassandra creates for each value in the column a timestamp. Is there a possibility to query the timestamp which is created with each column in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[writetime(col)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_writetime.html) is the CQL function you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT writetime(mycolumn) FROM mytable WHERE ...;
```

should be enough...